# Move just those files named as specific rows in a sample sheet

Tags: bash

Imagine I have these files in my working directory in bash:

```
123.tsv 456.tsv 789.tsv 101112.tsv 131415.tsv
```

and that I have this sample sheet (tab separated):

```
sampleID     tissue
123           lung
124           bone
456           lung
457           bone
```

Now, I want to move those files corresponding to lung samples to a new directory, so I would like to have the following files in the new directory:

```
123.tsv
456.tsv
```

I was trying to use:

```
awk -F"\t" '$2 == "lung"'
```

But I am not sure about how to include this in a for loop to select filenames included in the first column of the output file from the awk command.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
me=$( basename "${0}" )

# Adjust these as needed. If you want to use your current
# working directory change (or remove) `/tmp/` to `./`.
old_dir="/tmp/foo"
new_dir="/tmp/bar"
list="/tmp/sample_sheet"

# Make sure all the pieces are available. Exit if not.
if [ ! -d "${old_dir}" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: ${me}: Source '${old_dir}' does not exist." 1>&2
    exit 1
elif [ ! -d "${new_dir}" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: ${me}: Target '${new_dir}' does not exist." 1>&2
    exit 2
elif [ ! -r "${list}" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: ${me}: Sample sheet input '${list}' does not exist." 1>&2
    exit 3
fi

# Iterate over the first column in `${list}`.
for file in $( awk 'NR>1 && $2=="lung" {print $1".tsv"}' "${list}" )
do
    # If the file exists move it, if not do nothing.
    if [ -f "${old_dir}/${file}" ]
    then
        echo "INFO: ${me}: mv ${old_dir}/${file} ${new_dir}/${file}"
        mv "${old_dir}/${file}" "${new_dir}/${file}"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If row number is larger 1 and second column contains `lung` then print content of first column with some text around it:

```
mkdir new_dir
awk 'NR>1 && $2=="lung" {print "mv", $1 ".tsv new_dir"}' sample.sheet
```

If output looks fine, append `| sh` to `awk` line to execute commands.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that you can run like, for example, this:

```
./move_files.sh lung
```

This works for both cases (lung and bone), and is general. Put this into a file called **move_files.sh:**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=$(sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\( *$1\)/\1/g" <(grep $1 eg.sheet))
if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
  mkdir $1
fi
for t in ${files[@]}; do
  mv "./$t.tsv" $1
done
```

With the following directory content:

```
101112.tsv  123.tsv  124.tsv  131415.tsv  456.tsv  457.tsv  789.tsv  eg.sheet  move_files.sh
```

and **eg.sheet** containing:

```
sampleID     tissue
123           lung
124           bone
456           lung
457           bone
```

... running the script with

```
./move_files.sh lung
```

... results in **123.tsv** and **456.tsv** being moved into a newly created **lung** directory (or simply moved there if the directory already exists).

You can then simply run

```
./move_files.sh bone
```

to move **124.tsv** and **457.tsv** to a newly created **bone** directory. Of course this is then generalisable to whatever is in **eg.sheet**.

---

**Side note:** you must run `chomd +x move_files.sh` in order to use it in the way I've suggested. Otherwise, you can invoke it with `bash move_files.sh lung` instead.

---

## EDIT:

To address the point raised by keithpjolley in the comments, this can still work with "tissues" such as "eye lash" just by quoting the `$1` variable throughout and by calling it with a quoted string (e.g., `./move_files.sh "eye lash"`):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files=$(sed -e "s/\([0-9]\{3\}\)\( *$1\)/\1/g" <(grep "$1" eg.sheet))
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then
  mkdir "$1"
fi
for t in ${files[@]}; do
  mv "./$t.tsv" "$1"
done
```

Comment: i had started to generalize my answer to segregate out different "tissues" but then decided that i needed to start with a new approach because one of my "tissues" was "eye lash" and it messed everything up. :)   (and figured i'd wait until someone asked that question!)

Comment: @keithpjolley I didn't think the tissue names would contain spaces, but I've updated my answer to address this, thanks. Also, it might be worth noting that this particular regex expects the filenames to be 3 digits long ... this can be overcome by just changing the `\{3\}` part to give a range instead (`\{3,6\}` would match files with 3-6 digits, or to match a filename with one or more digits then the first matching group would be `\([0-9]\+\)`)